# Noob has problems in coding (text combat system)

Tags: c++

I recently started trying to programm in C++. I was creating a combat system for my text adventure, but I came across a few problems. For example, I want the battle to end when either you or the opponent dies. Currently it only ends if both die. The other one is you can get healed by attacks if your defence is bigger than the attack. Can you please help the noob here? :D Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iso646.h>
int main()
{
int att, def, hp, eatt, edef, ehp, pinput, einput;
cout<<"Your damgae"<<endl;
cin>>att;
cout<<"Your defence"<<endl;
cin>>def;
cout<<"Your hp"<<endl;
cin>>hp;
cout<<"Enemy attack"<<endl;
cin>>eatt;
cout<<"Enemy defence"<<endl;
cin>>edef;
cout<<"Enemy hp"<<endl;
cin>>ehp;
do {
    srand (time(NULL));
    einput=rand()%2+1;
    cout<<"1) attack 2) defend"<<endl;
    cin>>pinput;
    if (pinput==1) {
                   if (einput==1) {
                                  cout<<"enemy defends"<<endl;
                                  att=att-edef;
                                  ehp=ehp-att;
                                  cout<<"Enemy hp now is:"<<ehp<<endl;
                                  att=att+edef;
                                  }
                   if (einput==2) {
                                  cout<<"enemy doesn't defend but attacks you too"<<endl;
                                  hp=hp-eatt;
                                  ehp=ehp-att;
                                  cout<<"Your hp is:"<<hp<<endl;
                                  cout<<"Enemy hp now is:"<<ehp<<endl;
                                  }
                   }
    if (pinput==2) {
                   if (einput==1) cout<<"enemy stands in defence aswell"<<endl;
                   if (einput==2) {
                                  cout<<"enemy attacks you"<<endl;
                                  eatt=eatt-def;
                                  hp=hp-eatt;
                                  eatt=eatt+def;
                                  cout<<"Your hp is:"<<hp<<endl;
                                  }
                                  }


                   }
                   while (ehp>0||hp>0);
                   if (ehp<1) cout<<"You win"<<endl;
                   if (hp<1) cout<<"You die"<<endl;


 system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for all the help, and sorry for any dumb mistakes I made.

Comment: I don't know if it's your compiler or the source you're learning from, but your code looks like it is a decade old. There's nothing wrong with that, but since you mentioned you are learning I suggest you use a more up to date compiler/book. The headers "iostream.h" etc. have been changed in the past to just "iostream" etc. without the ".h", and all the things from the standard library are in namespace std, so you need to put a `using std::cout; using std::cin;` somewhere appropriate.

Comment: Ok I will try using just iostream but I didn't really undestand the second part with namespace std stuff. Sorry, english isn't my first language and as I mentioned I am new. I am loving this tho. I started learning like 3 days ago from my IT teacher, who taught me the basics like making a calculator and using IF stuff. Everything else I learnt from internet or figured out myself. Thanks for the feedback! But the last problem stands - how do I make it so attacks can't heal you or the opponent?

Comment: Also could you add me on skype? I would like to ask some stuff that won't really fit here or be reasonable to put here. Mine is: viktor11121998

Comment: The healing problem is that you allow negative values for `att` or `eatt`, which is effectively healing. You can change your code to `att= att>def ? att-def : 0;` or even better `#include <algorithm>` and `att=std::min(0, att-def);`, or use that `if` stuff like `if (att-def >0) att=att-def; else att=0;`. Skype doesn't work on my computer since I don't have 32 bit libraries installed and skype doesn't support 64 bit on linux. Sorry.

Comment: Wow youre amazing, wish i could upvote you a thousand times. Ill probs implement it wrong at ruin everything but thats the glory of programming i guesss :D about the skype thing: dont worry. But maybe you have steam? that could be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is easily solved, use `&&` not `||`, you want to carry on while your hit points are > 0 **and** the enemy hits points are > 0.

```
while (ehp>0 && hp>0);
```

Comment: Ooh my god thank you so much! I searched the internet but couldn't find the right wording for my question. Anyways, thanks alot! Only one problem to go and I got myself a combat system.

Comment: @NyanScout If you believe the answer is good, you should upvote it. If it is the best answer which completely solves your problem (which this one doesn't), you should accept it.

Comment: I tried to upvote it but I need reputation which I don't have sadly.

Comment: I decided to accept the answer since noone seems to know how to fix the healing. Thanks for the fast help John!